# Can I use xamarin to upload an app to my personal phone on windows?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I need an app on my personal phone without publishing it and I'm an Iphone user. I don't have a MAC and I don't think I can afford it. I only have a windows and a linux machine.

My first instinct is to use react-native for this task but as far as I'm concerned I need to create an expo app to run on my Iphone, but I wan't it as an app since what I actually need is to send notifications to my phone while I'm out to work.

I've heard about about xamarin before and it peaked my interest. I want to learn C# as well and since this is a small side project I think it's a great opportunity to learn C#.

But the question is: Can I make a local app for my Iphone on windows using Xamarin, upload it to my phone and use it?

Comment: No matter what language or environment meant you use to develop your app, you need macOS and Xcode tools to build,  sign and deploy it. There are "Mac in cloud" services like code magic and others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Xamarin Hot Restart` to debug the project on your local device.

Following the steps below to make sure the project can run on the pysical device:

1. Ensure the iOS project is set as the startup project and the build
   configuration is set to Debug|iPhone.
   If this is an existing project, go to `Build > Configuration Manager`…
   and ensure Deploy is enabled for the iOS project.
2. Select and click `Local Device` in the toolbar to launch the setup
   wizard.
3. If iTunes is not installed, click Download iTunes to download the
   installer. Click Next when the iTunes installation is complete.
4. Connect an iOS device to your machine. If a device was already
   plugged in, unplug then reconnect it. The device name will appear in
   the wizard once it is detected. Click Next.
5. Enter your Apple Developer account credentials and click Next.
6. Select a development team using the dropdown menu in order to enable
   [automatic provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning) in the project. Click Finish.

Comment: So, making sure, I will have the app in debug mode on my local machine, even if I unplug the phone will it still be there? Also another question since I don't know it: Do I have to upload it to the appstore with an account?

Comment: First, if you unplug the phone it will not be there because it based on the hot reload. Second, you do not need to upload it to the Appstore but you need an apple developer account.

Comment: Thanks, one more question, is there a way to keep my app after I unplug the phone? That's what I'm looking for actually.

Comment: You need a macOS device to achieve this.

Comment: Will a VM or a docker image do the trick?

Comment: Yes, you can use the VM.